# Suspend posting to full BufferAction

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a simple bounded `BufferBlock` which I post and receive data from.
The elements I push into are rows from db. To save some memory and not load all rows into `BufferBlock` I use `BoundedCapacity`.

The problem is that it works not as I expect it to work, actually it doesn't post it to the `BufferBlock` if it's full as expected, but it keeps reading from db and saves it (probably) somewhere in memory so it can push it to the `BufferBlock` later in the moment it can.

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    // queue is the bounded BufferBlock
    // why does it keep reading even though queue is full?
    MyObj obj = GetMyObjByReader(reader);
    await queue.SendAsync(obj);
}
```

The queue is linked to a transformer which does his job, but it's not that relevant.

I need somehow to await *until* the queue is not full.

Comment: 1. Show how you create the block. 2. `BufferAction`, `CapcityBounded` aren't things in TPL Dataflow.

Comment: @i3arnon Sorry, I've ment `BufferBlock` as I specified along the whole question and `BoundedCapacity`, just swapped the words. Hope it makes more sense now :).

Comment: I assumed so. What's actually important is the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say:

> "The queue is linked to a transformer which does his job, but it's not that relevant."

If by "transformer" you mean `TransformBlock` (and I assume you do) what probably happens is that you link the `TransformBlock` to the `BufferBlock` but only limit the size of the `BufferBlock` with `BoundedCapacity`.

Since the `TransformBlock` is unbounded (which is the default) everything you post to the `BufferBlock` is immediately transferred to the `TransformBlock`'s `InputQueue` and that's why your memory increases.

Bounding just a single block in the pipe doesn't bound the entire pipe. You need to bound each block individually.

Comment: In this case, it might be enough to not have the `BufferBlock` at all, and just send directly to the bounded `TransformBlock`.